# Two Blocks for sort filter Views -- Drupal 7

Tags: 7, views

I have a view in Drupal 7 with results including a field of date and another with price, I need to sort the results by means of these two fields when I click on the appropriate link (not button or dropbox radio), but the trick is I need add the different **sort filter** into two separate blocks, because each block will have a different per user context.

Besides the filters should be links. Any idea how to work this?

[image]

Comment: which part are you getting stuck on? the filtering? positioning two views side-by-side? the link?

Answer (score 0):

I dun really get what you mean. I presume you are trying let admin or user to able to do sorting.

I have two ideas

Under format change from unformatted list to table. At this case you are able to do sorting by click table header.

Another one is under sort criteria, add any content you want to sort and select expose.

If I wrong, can show me any example??